# In game engine, all texts change color to white

Tags: game-engine, text-object

Before render:

[image]

After render:

[image]

The render is set to blender game. How do I fix this?

---

When I want add a material for a text, in first step I'm selected text then set a material color on diffuse option (like green color) for that:

[image]

but in the rendering time, this problem is occurred:

[image]

This problem only occurs to texts.

Comment: Why are you calling running the game "render"?

Answer (score 0):

Set Object color in Properties panel > display
If you want text look similar as in the 3D view just convert the text to mesh. Alt+C > Convert to mesh

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it and in new post I've explained how to solve the problem.

Comment: If you have solved the issue, tick one of the answers so that this question no longer appears in the unanswered questions section.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem and I want say how to solve it:

When you add a text, you can set a color with material tab and diffuse menu (for example I choose red color).

Note:In material tab, you must select "Data":

[image]

Before rendering, select your text and press ALT+C then choose "Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text" finally press P key.